# How to update plugin when I can't sign in?

Tags: wordpress

I am getting this message when trying to login

```
Warning: Declaration of Axiom_Plugin_Updater::download_package($package) should be compatible with WP_Upgrader::download_package($package, $check_signatures = false) in /var/www/fantasine.dk/public_html/wp-content/plugins/masterslider/admin/includes/classes/class-axiom-plugin-updater.php on line 29

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/fantasine.dk/public_html/wp-content/plugins/masterslider/admin/includes/classes/class-axiom-plugin-updater.php:29) in /var/www/fantasine.dk/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1251

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/fantasine.dk/public_html/wp-content/plugins/masterslider/admin/includes/classes/class-axiom-plugin-updater.php:29) in /var/www/fantasine.dk/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1254
```

Is there any way I can fix this when I can't log in to the dashboard?

I am thinking maybe it would be possible through ftp login? If so, how do I go about it?
Also, is there a way to take a back up of the site when I can't log in to dashboard?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Log in via FTP, and change the plugin folder name, e.g. add `-bak` to the folder name. This will disable the plugin. For backup, you would need to use a server tool, like phpMyAdmin (to export the database) or if you have a CPanel type interface there may be a backup feature.

Comment: I've had multiple problems in the past with various websites that have used the 'masterslider' plugin - It's because it is only compatible with WordPress versions up to 5.0  - so if you're running anything later than that, you'll run into issues. If you login via FTP and delete (or rename) plugin folder, you should be able to access the backend again.